# Cross-platform Java with native libraries

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to implement a wrapper for native libraries that will be consumed via JNI in a Java application.  I want to make installation of the program be as simple as "Unzip this file and run".

I've worked through most of the wrapper so far, getting it to unzip the native libraries from inside the platform-specific JAR file and setting the -Djava.native.lib variable at runtime.  I've hit one last roadblock due to unsatisfied link errors.

On Windows, the DLLs that I'm calling link against msvcr100.dll.  While the DLLs that I'm calling into are getting picked up by java.native.lib, msvcr100.dll isn't.  I don't want to have to require the user to install the C++ runtime before using our app, so we are packaging the DLL file right along side the other DLLs.

As far as I understand, to get things to work we need to put the folder that contains msvcr100.dll on the PATH.  I tried using reflection to change the environment inside the application to add the unpack directory to the PATH environmental variable.  After this was unsuccessful, I recalled that I was only modifying a copy of the environment.

Is there some way that I can fix the unsatisfied link error without requiring any additional system setup (installing the runtime, hand modification of PATH, etc)?  I would think it is possible since I've encountered other pieces of software (SWT, JOGL) that package native libraries that don't exhibit this issue.

Comment: If you manually modify the path, does it all work for you?  That would at least rule out other things, such as incompatible bitness of the dll and JVM.

Comment: You can load your DLL via `LoadLibraryEx` with an option to search the same directory as the DLL for dependent DLLs.

Comment: Java comes with an excellent installer, called [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).  It will handle installation, including native libraries.  It can handle many other aspects of installation, such as adding a desktop icon, adding a start menu entry, and setting up file associations.  Using it is quite easy:  Just write a short XML file with a .jnlp extension that describes your application.

Comment: @whiskeyspider It does indeed work and that's how we've been doing it for a couple of years. Want to move away from manual modification.

Comment: @VGR JWS does not work in our environment due to security restrictions. Unfortunately, a zip file is the only way we're allowed to distribute our software.

Comment: Do you write one of the native libraries yourself? Modifying the PATH inside there should get you around the "copy of the environment" problem. (SWT doesn't reference the VS runtime BTW)

Comment: @user2543253 The native libraries are from an open source project, but we had to compile them ourselves in order to support multiple platforms.  Only one person on the team has the tools or the knowledge to attempt to recompile without the runtime and he isn't available to do that right now.

Comment: I ended up using System.load() to manually load the depended-upon libraries.  I had to do a little trial and error to figure out the libraries that needed to be manually loaded and what order to load them in.  It's not optimal, but it works.

Comment: Why not looking at the source code of GlueGen (used by JOGL)? We use System.load() too: https://github.com/sgothel/gluegen/blob/master/src/java/com/jogamp/common/jvm/JNILibLoaderBase.java#L575

Comment: Would something like what [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) does satisfy your needs? It basically does all the bundling and extracting of native libraries across platforms.

Comment: @SamuelAudet GlueGen doesn't have this kind of bug as it can be built without MSVCRT: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacpp-project/I4uK7rLv9vg

Comment: @gouessej It's not a bug in JavaCPP. Nothing prevents us from building the library with something like MinGW, in which case we don't need to rely on incompatible libraries from Microsoft.

Comment: @SamuelAudet Then, I advise you to build your binaries (those available in the binary archive mentioned in the "Downloads" section on Github) without MSVCRT and to mention MinGW in your instructions in the "Required softwares" section. GlueGen is able to generate very efficient bindings to AWT, OpenGL & OpenGL ES, OpenAL and OpenCL. Moreover, our Windows binaries are built without Visual Studio. If you really want to compare your library with GlueGen, generate some bindings to those libraries and write a lot of code so that it is usable with the most commonly used native windowing toolkits.

Comment: @gouessej Sure, I would welcome patches to have more stuff built with MinGW! And for more libraries as well, instructions here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Create-New-Presets But CUDA doesn't support MinGW/GCC on Windows, so we still have to use MSVC for some things...

Comment: @SamuelAudet There is a way to build your libraries with Visual Studio but without the need of MSVCRT at runtime, look at the static linking but the problem remains with Cuda. Do you plan to use OpenCL?